# DLL Inclusion in Multiple Developers Project with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 for my solution. We are a couple of developers on the same project and we are using SVN. My Question is: **What is a good way of including external dlls referenced from a project?** And if the dll is used accross many projects in the solution, do you still put the DLL in each one of the project?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer (although I don't know how "Best Practice" this is) to keep a "Reference Assemblies" folder under the root of my project (on the same level as my "trunk" folder) that I keep all of my external DLLs in, then reference them from there in my project. That way, whenever anyone checks-out the project, the reference location for the DLLs will be the same.

Comment: For what it's worth, I do exactly like this, and it has always worked well (from a small team to a team of 20 people).

Comment: nice, that's what I was going to do, I just wasn't sure if there were not any problems with that solution (I don't have a lot of experience in .net). Thanks!